# how to solve this error Syntax error, in spring boot insert "Type VariableDeclaratorId" to complete FormalParameterList?

Tags: spring-boot, maven

i would like to conceive and deploy an API using springboot, for that i wrote a code to get products,
here is the model :

```
          public class Product {
          private int id;
         private String nom;
         private int prix;

          public Product() {
          }


          public Product(int id, String nom, int prix) {
          this.id=id;
          this.nom=nom;
          this.prix=prix;
         }
```

of course i put getters and setters
and there is the controller

```
         import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
         import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
         import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
         import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
         import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
         import com.ecommerce.microcommerce.model.Product;

         @RestController
         public class ProductController {
         //Récupérer la liste des produits
          @RequestMapping(value="/Produits", method=RequestMethod.GET)
         public String listeProduits() {
         return "Un exemple de produit";
           }

         //Récupérer un produit par son Id
         @GetMapping(value="/Produits/{id}")
          public Product afficherUnProduit(@PathVariableintid) {
            Product product=new Product(id, new String("Aspirateur"), 100 );
            return product;
            }
          }
```

since i wrote the **afficherUnProduit** method i had the error mentionned in the title.
the red line appears on **@PathVariableintid**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a typo

```
public Product afficherUnProduit(@PathVariable int id) {}//in your code it is @PathVariableintid
```